# How safe is it to send a plain text password using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, security, authentication

Maybe the title is badly phrased but couldn't think of a better way of saying it.

I am working on a login system at the moment (nothing formal, just experimenting) and was planning on using PHPLiveX (an AJAX library) for some features. Basically you create some PHP functions which are then called via JavaScript. You can add parameters (getElementById) to the JavaScript that are transfered to the PHP function.

What I really wanted to know is whether it is safe to just call the function from JavaScript without encrypting the password first, then letting the PHP function encrypt it (SHA256 in this case). Can the data transfered via AJAX be intercepted? If so how likely is this?

Comment: What is the best way of securing this then, other than using SSL? If it were possible to hash a password in JavaScript is this a resaonable solution?

Comment: If you hash the password in JavaScript, it's still going to be visible to anyone sniffing the traffic (it will just be hashed!) An attacker could trivially replay this request with the hashed password in it

Comment: And SSL will solve this problem?

Comment: SSL will encrypt the entire POST request (and reply for that matter).  So yes, it'll fix this problem.

Comment: If you don't already intimately understand the security implications here, you really should not be designing an authorization system.   There are plenty of ready-built solutions out there, like PEAR Auth.

Comment: Hi, the reason i am doing this is to understand it better. I am not implementing this for anything serious or formal at all.

Comment: SOLUTION: transfer a "challenge" (cryptographically secure random number) to the client _tied to the session_. Have the client hash the password, then hash in the challenge, then send it. An attacker sniffing the result would need to also to have hijacked the session to be able to use the result.

Comment: Yeah, reimplement SSL in Javascript and in your application.  That's much easier than just flipping a switch in your web server config!

Comment: Sod it! I'm gonna use OpenID.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No more-or-less safe than a normal HTTP POST request issued by a browser (as in from a `<form>`)

The "fix" for this is the same "fix" for non-AJAX requests - use SSL.

Comment: Good answer, thankyou. So there are no security holes solely relating to AJAX?

Comment: Or challenge response, see my answer.

Comment: @briggins5 Like Peter says, AJAX is simply HTTP POST requests that happen out of turn, or 'asynchronously'. So, in a manner of speaking, you are correct. But, since AJAX is asynchronous, state changes in the client's browser are harder to understand, so its easier to mess up security.

Answer (score 20):

As others have mentioned, it's no more dangerous than sending an HTTP post from a form. In fact, it's the very same thing.

But if HTTPS isn't an option you can always use a challenge/response scheme over an unencrypted connection. Basically it works like this:

- Server has a SHA (or whatever hashing algorithm you prefer) hash of the user's password.
- Client has the password.
- Client requests (using unencrypted AJAX) that the server send a challenge (a random string of bytes; characters are fine.)
- Server creates a challenge and a challenge ID, and saves it with an expiration.
- Client recieves the challenge and challenge ID.
- Client hashes the password using SHA.
- Client hashes the resulting hash with the challenge appended in some way.
- Client sends the challenge ID (not the challenge itself) and the second resulting hash.
- Server looks up challenge using ID if it exists and hasn't expired.
- Server appends the challenge to the stored password hash and creates a hash using the same scheme as the client.
- Server compares its hash with the client. If it's the same, the user is authenticated.

It's actually pretty simple to set up once you get the idea. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) has some additional information on it.

**EDIT:** I noticed I forgot to mention, whether or not the authentication is successful you *must* delete the challenge, regardless. Giving the client multiple attempts on one challenge could lead to security issues.

Comment: Sounds like a good method. I would like some peoples opinions of how secure this is when compared to traditional authentication (just compraing username and password)?

Comment: How secure it is compared to just sending both the username and password as plain text? Well if you attach the value of 0 to that method, and my approach is some n > 0 (say .0005 even, for the sake of argument) my method is >1,000,000,000,000,000 times more secure.

Comment: I asked this same question a long time ago. Here is another link describing it (with some extra quirks): http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/viewreply.asp?ID=3353014

Comment: It is much easier to break this than it is to break SSL.  If you aren't salting the password, you can probably crack it in a matter of minutes with some downloaded rainbow tables.  If you are salting the password, the attacker can still capture the hashed password and attempt to guess it -- SHA1 is very fast, modern computers can try millions of passwords a second.  (Don't reinvent SSL!)

Comment: @jrockway: First, this isn't reinventing SSL. Challenge/Response is only good for determining when two parties know the same information. Second, Salts aren't secret and an acceptable salting method for defense against rainbow tables is: hash = SHA (SHA (password) . salt). In this set up, the salt is the challenge and it's purpose becomes two fold hash = SHA (SHA (password) . challenge). Third, I was using SHA1 as an example. There are much larger schemes available if you need additional safety.

Answer (score 7):

Whether you are sending the password via AJAX or via a normal form, it is still sent via a HTTP `POST` (hopefully) request. So you are not adding or removing anything security wise.

The only way to prevent someone from intercepting your password is by using SSL (via AJAX or not).

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are just plain HTTP request.

It behaves like ordinary HTTP request and also comes with all the advantage and disadvantage of it. It is not any safer.

To make your AJAX calls safe, there are several ways you can try:

1. Use SSL. SSL will encrypt messages between your user and your server. The disadvantage of SSL is that you will have to pay additional fee for valid SSL certificates. Invalid SSL certificates while usable, does not provide the same level of guarantee of security to the users.
2. Encrypt requests before being sent, client-side. E.g.: hash users' password before being sent over the network. Most of the time, you don't need users' plain text password anyway. This is not usable when users don't allow client side scripting to run.
3. And apart from common misleading information where POST is safer than GET, it is not. Both are equally open for attackers to see.

Comment: -1: Misleading answer. AJAX does the same request as a plain old form.

Comment: And which part of my answer that says "AJAX does NOT do the same request as a plain old form"?

Comment: @Adrian: Actually, it's the missing information that makes someone who doesn't have that knowledge to assume it is somehow different.

Comment: He said "misleading", not "blatantly incorrect".  And I agree with him, although I am not going to -1 you for it.  I'll just comment instead.

Comment: @Adrian - your #2 doesn't work because anyone that can sniff the traffic will see the hashed password and could easily replay it. The only benefit to hashing is that (if it's properly salted) it will make it very difficult to get pre-hashed password

Comment: @Josh Yep, it is prone to replay attack. Put one time token in.

Answer (score 1):

This is just as safe as having a login form that is not SSL secured be sent over the wire, like almost all forums out there do!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the target of your AJAX call is a trusted HTTPS:// page and you've made it every bit as secure as any of the other sends of the same information that the rest of your application is doing.  Most libraries / frameworks don't limit you to just HTTP:// for your AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be read.  Just like everything else without some kind of layer of security (See SSL)

To see it yourself run a tool like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) as you do your AJAX commands.

How likely? Not very, but the user's password will probably be saved in someone's log files in plain text.  If someone eventually found it, then it could be bad news.  Back in college, my networking class had access to some (semi) fancy routers.  We had assignments where we signed up for accounts on random websites.  As we did this, we noticed some very scary things on the log files in the routers.  This was an eye opener for me to think about how every communication is tracked and most likely logged somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The plain text password transmitted via AJAX will be as secure as the same password transmitted via a normal HTTP post. That is to say AJAX uses HTTP and can therefore be intercepted and sniffed. Your best bet is to use HTTPS (SSL).

For further reading on AJAX and security I'd recommend the following readings

- [Top 10 Ajax Security Holes and Driving Factors](http://www.net-security.org/article.php?id=956)
- [Ajax security holes and how to fill them](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/news/article/0,289142,sid8_gci1248648,00.html)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't safe. Don't send unencrypted passwords. It's very likely that they will be intercepted at some point you will have a major problem.

Here is a [video](http://ccp120.blogspot.com/2009/03/cracking-telnet-in-4-minutes.html) example of capturing a telnet password. Telnet sends in plain text and this nicely illustrates the major problem you have if you even think of doing this. Any two bit script kiddie can snag a plain text password faster than you can so "Oh my God, where did my database go?"

Comment: Care to provide any facts that back your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending it in the clear, so anyone with sniffing/listening/etc the client's network will be able to easily see the password.  The AJAX call is just a plain old HTTP message.  If you want to see this in action, fire up a copy of [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and make the request your self.  You will be able to see the password in the HTTP packet.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, SSL is the best solution here. However, you could hash the password on the client side. If you google for it, you'll find plenty of javascript implementations of md5.

Answer (score 0):

damn you guys worry me. SSL does not protect against the arp poisoning MITM attack. It would be fatal to worship SSL as you guys are. You must have a way to encrypt the password on the client side before it makes even one hop or else even a novice hacker will be able to intercept the password in plaintext

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One should also be very aware of potential security vulnerabilities when building an application that utilises Ajax.

The following site has some really good info in regards to Ajax and XSS or XSRF Attacks http://www.isecpartners.com/files/isec-attacking_ajax_applications.bh2006.pdf

Don't forget that when you make a remote function accessible to a javascript call, a user could simply guess the function call and modify it to do his/her bidding.