# Ajax login technique (backend php)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, hash

I read lots of info about login security, and most with Ajax.
Mainly I was thinking to pass via javascript the password and username in plain text, and in php hash it.
This way: 
JS plain text > php hash > database

What about hash twice during Ajax ? Do you think it's good?
Like this: 
JS hash > php hash > database

So I don't care about hackers during Ajax request and of course another hash on the server will make it more secure and it's one of the best hashing method I found. Using JS hashing I will never recive the real password on the server, but, I don't need the real password, just an hash to compare the passwords hashed.

Better with JS hashing or I can go with just php hash?

Comment: Maby duplicate or worth looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145132/how-safe-is-it-to-send-a-plain-text-password-using-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use HTTPS for your data exchange and the data is not to sensitive, php hashing should be fine.

If you only use HTTP, you will have the "normal" hacking problems, so you might want to try JS  hashing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your main concern is - a JS hash would only help if you expect that someone could be listening in on the communication between the client and the server. However if someone disables Javascript while registering and then enables it when logging in or simply goes to another computer, you won't know if the password in the db is hashed once, or twice.

Comment: I think that I must use SSL. So I will look about it. Sadly client side I can't check what's really happen and prevent changes.